# Object not found error 404 in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have some problem when i try to open another controller

```
http://localhost/ci/dashboard
```

getting error like this:

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19

---

link sourcecode: [sourcecode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/02l1oou8ucxaft9/code.7z)

Comment: Your question is not clear, what have you done, show code examples and `url` please.

Comment: try acessing http://localhost/ci/index.php/dashboard, and please show us the content of your config.php and routes.php

Comment: Yes, i can access with localhost/ci/index.php/dashboard, But how i can accees localhost/ci/dashboard

Answer (score 1):

If you Using WAMP server then open "httpd.conf" file, search 
  "**LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**" and remove # which in the start of the same line..
and 
 ***restart your WAMP Server***

Then add this code to your .htaccess file which is in the codeigniter folder (if not create it in the folder's **root)**:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Answer (score -1):

check first if apache is already way or not 
and may try to open localhost port problem 
and usually when in the ci enksripsi effect to open a web page

Comment: You answer is unclear. Could you please improve it by adding punctuation so that we can understand you.